# Facebook Business Locations: Adding new locations

Tags: facebook, local-seo, social-media

Anyone have experience with Facebook Business Locations?

I'm having trouble uploading new branches/locations to a client's FB page. They have a number of locations already successfully listed but they need to add more. We have uploaded a spreadsheet with all the required columns ([as specified by Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/224119578024377)) for both existing and new locations. It's been several weeks and the changes have not been made.

Do I need to upload a spreadsheet with JUST the new locations? Won't this remove the old ones?
Does anyone have any other suggestions / experiences as to why the changes may not have been made to the page?

Comment: It seems that you have done this correctly, if you already have locations set up, then you will need to include existing locations in the upload also. Have you set your visibility to publish?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Kirsty, I'll double-check the visibility setting :)